# cannot convert from System.Data.SqlDbType to System.Data.DbType

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, commandparameter, sqldbtype

```
DbCommand retcommmand;



var attachmentDetails = this.ConvertToDatatable<CurfewAttachmentDetails>(curfewRequestForSave.Attachment);
            List<CommandParameter> SqlparamUpdate = new List<CommandParameter>();
            // SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CurfewRelaxationId", curfewRequestForSave.CurfewRelaxationId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int64));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CurfewRelaxationId", curfewRequestForSave.CurfewRelaxationId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int64));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CurfewRelaxationRequestId", "TODO Code For WorkFlow", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CurfewRequestCode", String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_StaffSeqId", curfewRequestForSave.StaffSeqId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int64));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_RequestCategoryId", curfewRequestForSave.RequestCategoryId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_RequestTypeId", curfewRequestForSave.RequestTypeId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_Reason", curfewRequestForSave.Reason, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_PermissionRequiredFrom", curfewRequestForSave.PermissionRequiredFrom, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.DateTime));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_PermissionRequiredTill", curfewRequestForSave.PermissionRequiredTill, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.DateTime));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_RelationshipId", curfewRequestForSave.RelationshipId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_Spouse_Blood_Name", curfewRequestForSave.Spouse_Blood_Name, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_ReturnDate", curfewRequestForSave.ReturnDate, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.DateTime));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_ShiftTimmingsFrom", curfewRequestForSave.ShiftTimmingsFrom, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.DateTime));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_ShiftTimmingsTo", curfewRequestForSave.ShiftTimmingsTo, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.DateTime));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CreatedBy", curfewRequestForSave.StaffSeqId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int64));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_UpdatedBy", curfewRequestForSave.StaffSeqId, ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int64));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PI_CurfewRquestAttchMntDetails", attachmentDetails, ParameterDirection.Input,SqlDbType.Structured));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PO_MESSAGE", "", ParameterDirection.Output, DbType.String, 500));
            SqlparamUpdate.Add(new CommandParameter("@PO_RETURN_CODE", 0, ParameterDirection.Output, DbType.Int32));

            retcommmand = _sqldbframework.ExecuteSPNonQueryParm("QAG_GEMS_CURFEW_REQUEST_SAVE_DETAILS_PROC", SqlparamUpdate);
```

I am supposed to use `CommandParameter` as I am using a method defined by other team to insert to DB I cannot change to `SQLCommandParameter` in this scenario how I can pass table value parameter

I am getting this

> errorcannot convert from System.Data.SqlDbType to System.Data.DbType

Comment: If you cant change it to SQLCommandParameter from CommandParameter then this conversion error is inevitable.

Comment: So You mean only way to do bulk Insert is XML

Comment: If you leave out the dbtype (SqlDbType.Structured) ADO.Net will infer the type for the provider in use. You can try that, if the database is MS SQL then it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I have changed the code for using XML even changed the SP to accept XML , But will try that